# R Shiny: convert reactive output in integer

Tags: r, integer, shiny

I have a web application where I use the tool Shiny Server. In the file `ui.R`, I have a `checkboxGroupInput`. The `checkboxGroupInput` ID is "salida":

```
    checkboxGroupInput("salida","Salida:",
                       c(salida_datos$column_name), selected = "temp"),
```

In the  file `server.R`, I have the following code:

```
totalgraficas <- reactiveValues(numero=0)
numerograficas <- reactive({
   for(i in 1:length(input$salida))
   {
     if(input$salida[i] == "temp" || input$salida[i] == "temp_int")
     {
        totalgraficas$numero = totalgraficas$numero +1
     }        
   }
   return(totalgraficas$numero)
})

output$graficaDatos = renderPlot({

    LAS = 2 
    MFROW = c(numerograficas,1) #Filas y columnas
    MAR =  c(4,4,1,1) #Margenes

    par(las= LAS, mfrow= MFROW, mar= MAR)

    ...
```

I get the following error

```
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

I need the output of "numerograficas" be a integer for use in the function `mfrow`

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need `isolate(totalgraficas$numero)` to get the value of `totalgraficas$numero`. I do not have your data but below is a dummy example that gets integers.

```
 library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput("salida","Salida:",
                       c("a", "temp_int", "temp"), selected = "temp"),
    verbatimTextOutput("printN")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    totalgraficas <- reactiveValues(numero=0)
    numerograficas <- reactive({
        for(i in 1:length(input$salida)) {
            if(input$salida[i] == "temp" || input$salida[i] == "temp_int") {
                ########################################################
                # use isolate() to get the value of totalgraficas$numero
                totalgraficas$numero <- isolate(totalgraficas$numero) +1
            }        
        }
        return(totalgraficas$numero)
    })
    output$printN <- renderPrint({
        numerograficas()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```